# How do I create a one time link with PHP and include it on an E-mail?

Tags: php, forms, email, hyperlink

Basically I've created this form where users input an applicants user information and E-mail address. I need to create a onetime link that directs the user back to my website. The link expires once clicked and should be included together with the message of the E-mail.

The form below works as intended and sends users an e-mail address with whatever you type into the form. But I have no idea on how to make a hyperlink be included in the e-mail let alone how to generate a hyperlink for each new user.

Form:

```
<form action="email_script.php" method="POST">
Ämne: <input type="text" name="subject" style="width: 500px;"/><br>
Kandidatens E-postadress: <input type="text" name="minemail" style="width: 500px;"/><br>
Kandidatens E-postadress: <input type="text" name="kanemail" style="width: 500px;"/><br>
Meddelande: <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="message" style="width: 500px"></textarea> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Skicka test">
</form>
```

This is the PHP script:

```
<?php
$from=$_POST['minemail'];
$email=$_POST['kanemail'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$company=dashboardcompany.php;

mail($email, $subject, $message, "Från: ".$from);

print "Ditt meddelande har skickats: <br>$email<br>$subject<br>$message<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a database? The standard method is to create a 'token' in the database which either expires or gets deleted once it gets used.

Comment: I have made a database table with two columns: token (Primary) char(40), tstamp (int 10).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an activation hash with PHP doing something like this, which returns a 40 character string to store in the database along with the other user data

```
$user_activation_hash = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
```

Then within your `$message` create a link with the hash.

```
$link = "mysite.com/activate.php?code=".$user_activation_hash;
```

When the user clicks, you will need to capture the code on the `activate.php` page using this

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
```

Then from there perform your check in the database

Answer (score 0):

For each email you create, generate an ID with something like [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). Insert it into your database.

Inside your $message (which already has HTML formatting), include your link

```
 <a href="https://example.com/register.php?link=asdf1a234">Click to register</a>
```

On your register.php page, check your DB to make sure that code is still there, allow the registration to commence, and delete the code (or mark it used -- might be useful if someone clicks more than once).